# GCE: ERROR The resource <name> already exists (but it doesn't)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am not sure if this is a bug or an error on my  side.

I created and instance on GCE and then proceeded to delete it. The deletion failed with message:

> The resource 'projects/[PROJECT]/zones/[ZONE]/instances/[INSTANCE]'
>   was not found

Please note that this is an automated process that runs a couple times per day, so there wasn't a typo inside the commands.

Nevertheless, the instance was deleted.

Now, every time I try to create an instance with the same name, I get:

```
NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - The resource 'projects/[PROJECT]/zones/[ZONE]/instances/[INSTANCE]' already exists
```

But I can't see the instance or its disk anywhere in the Developers Console, neither can I delete it from the command line since I get a `resource not found`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just a browser cache/cookies issue, where your cache still recognizes the resource name as existing when the resource is already deleted. Clearing the browser cache and cookies or using private browsing/incognito mode should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Opening

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair

in a browser, entering the project ID + submitting has fixed a problem with the same error message for me.